# Help me solve a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Help me please with this one: $$y'=\arcsin(y+2x-1)$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In such examples, you have something of type $y' = f(y+2x-1)$ for some function $f$. Those terms under $f$ are a bit challening, so why not replace it "outside" $f$, where we can somehow handle it. By that I mean, let $u(x) = y(x)+2x-1$. Then $u'(x)=y'(x) + 2$ so that $y'(x) = u'(x) - 2$.

After substituting we get an equation of type $$ u'(x)  = \arcsin(u(x)) + 2$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: I’m afraid I can’t proceed. Can you please go on?

Comment: Divide (why it's non-zero ?) to get $\frac{u'}{\arcsin(u)+2} = 1$ so that $\int \frac{du}{\arcsin(u)+2} = x + C$, but I doubt there is closed form in terms of elementary functions for such an integral.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $u=2x+y-1$ and then
$$ u'=2+\arcsin(u)$$
which is separable.